# Ethernet RJ45 Mg Jacks - CMC placement

Tags: voltage, transformer, ethernet, magnetics, common-mode

Ethernet RJ45 Mg Jacks. Some have common mode chokes on the PHY side and some have chokes on the cable side. What's the difference?

Some examples:

https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Prototyping/MagJack.pdf

https://www.we-online.com/components/products/datasheet/74980111211.pdf

Comment: What do you consider cable side and connector side? You need a choke between the cable and the phy. Both of those jacks have that.

Comment: My question is, which is better and why? PHY --- (CMC - TRANSFORMER) --- CABLE, or PHY ---- (TRANSFORMER - CMC) --- CABLE?

Comment: Better in which way, for what purpose? If they both are good enough then neither needs to be better.

Comment: Like, since the placement is different, there must be some sort of better performance in either one in the perspective of EMC right? @Justme